# It is possible to start directly a call intent from one app to another without a chooser popup?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that sends a call intent to another app (CsipSimple).

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.phone.extra.NEW_CALL_INTENT");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("csip:" + number));
startActivity(intent);
```

But every time a chooser dialog is poping up to choose the CsipSimple app. Is there a way to avoid this chooser and use directly a defined app.

I found that it is possible to define the class name of the activity:

```
intent.setClassName("com.csipsimple.ui.outgoingcall", "com.csipsimple.ui.outgoingcall.OutgoingCallChooser");
```

But this doesn't work, i assume that this can only work if the intent caller and CsipSimple are both in the same process.

Comment: I changed the CsipSimple app with SipDroid and everything worked fine. If I send the same intent, and SipDroid is running, SipDroid receives the intent and creating a new call.

Comment: i also changed Uri.parse("csip:" + number) to Uri.parse("sip:" + number)